# OSMnx undirected graphs and (u, v, k) order

Tags: python, geopandas, osmnx

I'm wondering about directed (MultiGraph) and undirected (MultiDiGraph) representations of OSMnx networks with respect to (1) finding the nearest edge and (2) writing the network and its attributes to disk in a reproducible way.

1. I call osmnx.simplification.consolidate_intersections, combining OSM way IDs for some edges.
2. I then convert the graph to GeoDataFrames and do some more preprocessing.
3. Then I use osmnx.distance.nearest_edges to locate observations to edges (i.e. streets); for this I need to change the geodataframes back to a graph.

I use the (u, v, key) of the nearest edges to cross reference observations and street segment geometry throughout the analysis.  Converting back and forth from geodataframes to networkx graph does not preserve the (u, v, k) order of the edge indices.

Is there any unique and unchanging identifier for edges after an OSMnx graph goes through osmnx.simplification.consolidate_intersections?

Edit: As requested, below is a short example illustrating that the [u, v, key] sets change on reading and writing the graph to disk from GeoDataFrames.  From [this github issue](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/issues/356#issuecomment-568667636) and [the networkx docs](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.to_undirected.html#networkx-digraph-to-undirected) I see that my assumption that [u, v, key] would not change won't hold.  I've worked around this by doing more of my preprocessing using the networkx.MultiGraph representation of the network instead of the GeoDataFrame representation and only converting to GeoDataFrames and writing to disk once, at the end of the pipeline.

```py
import osmnx as ox
import geopandas as gpd
TRANSVERSE_MERCATOR_NZ = 'EPSG:2193'
fname_gpkg = '/tmp/test.gpkg'
fname_graphml = '/tmp/test.graphml'

# 1) create an OSMnx graph for Auckland, New Zealand.  Reproject,
# consolidate intersections, convert to undirected.  Do some analyses:
# assigning the "road_class" variable serves here as a placeholder.
# Save to geopackage.
g = ox.graph_from_place(
    ['NZ-AUK'], network_type="drive", retain_all=True
)
# reproject, consolidate, undirect
gp = ox.projection.project_graph(g, TRANSVERSE_MERCATOR_NZ)
g_simplified = ox.simplification.consolidate_intersections(gp, tolerance=30)
g_simplified_undirected = ox.utils_graph.get_undirected(g_simplified)
# get geodataframes and add a column to edges
gdf_nodes_0, gdf_edges_0 = ox.utils_graph.graph_to_gdfs(g_simplified_undirected)
gdf_edges_0['road_class'] = 1  # placeholder for more complicated stuff
# convert back to graph and save to geopackage
g_from_frames = ox.utils_graph.graph_from_gdfs(gdf_nodes_0, gdf_edges_0)
g_for_output = ox.utils_graph.get_undirected(g_from_frames)
ox.io.save_graph_geopackage(g_for_output, fname_gpkg)

# 2) load the saved geopackage back to GeoDataFrames, demonstrate that
# the u, v, k values have changed.
gdf_nodes_1 = gpd.read_file(fname_gpkg,
                            layer='nodes').set_index('osmid')
gdf_edges_1 = gpd.read_file(fname_gpkg,
                            layer='edges').set_index(['u', 'v', 'key'])
# show that the network saved to the geopackage and the network loaded
# from the geopackage have edges with different u, v, w indices
assert gdf_nodes_1.index.is_unique and gdf_edges_1.index.is_unique
graph_attrs = {'crs': 'epsg:2193', 'simplified': True}

idx_0 = gdf_edges_0.reset_index()[['u', 'v', 'key']]
idx_1 = gdf_edges_1.reset_index()[['u', 'v', 'key']]

only_0 = idx_0.merge(idx_1, how='outer', indicator=True).loc[lambda x: x['_merge'] == 'left_only']
only_1 = idx_0.merge(idx_1, how='outer', indicator=True).loc[lambda x: x['_merge'] == 'right_only']

# only_0 contains [u, v, key] sets that are in gdf_edges_0 but not gdf_edges_1.
# only_1 contains [u, v, key] sets that are in gdf_edges_1 but not gdf_edges_0.
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example: the answer in this case will depend on your specific parametrization.

Comment: posted a small example as requested.  I've managed to rework my processing pipeline to avoid the problems that arose from incorrect assumptions I made about the [u, v, key] sets not changing.

Comment: Thanks, @gboeing, for this excellent tool.  It's fantastically useful.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any unique and unchanging identifier for edges after an OSMnx graph goes through osmnx.simplification.consolidate_intersections?

The edges change upon consolidation because the nodes change upon consolidation. Edges are uniquely identified by their endpoint nodes plus a key, as the tuple `(u, v, k)`. So when the nodes change, the edges' unique identifiers change. However, you can take an edge's unique identifier `(u, v, k)`, look up the corresponding nodes in the consolidated graph, and inspect their `osmid_original` attributes:

```py
# download, project, consolidate graph
G = ox.graph_from_place('Piedmont, CA, USA', network_type='drive')
Gp = ox.project_graph(G)
Gc = ox.consolidate_intersections(Gp)

# select the first edge
u, v, k = list(Gc.edges)[0]

# inspect this edge's attributes
print(Gc.edges[(u, v, k)])

# what was the original OSM ID of this edge's u and v nodes?
u_original = Gc.nodes[u]['osmid_original']
v_original = Gc.nodes[v]['osmid_original']

# inspect the original edge's attributes
print(G.edges[(u_original, v_original, k)])
```

So, the edges are uniquely identified by their nodes, and the nodes in the consolidated graph have an attribute to link them back to their original OSM IDs. However, this will not always work, as some individual nodes in the consolidated graph (by definition) comprise multiple nodes from the original graph, making the look-up impossible. Consolidation inherently reduces information for the sake of better theoretical correspondence.